# Question type corpus

Tags: english, computational-linguistics, corpora, questions

I'm looking for a corpus that contains questions and question types.
Like in this article, but they didn't attach any link to their corpus.
http://polibits.gelbukh.com/2009_40/40_01.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this dataset, which is quite good, but I think it has to be more on the internet. 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/QA/QC/